# Finding the largest difference between multiple sets of numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I've attempted to create a program which processes a list of outcomes for football games while also processing the results.

The way my program works is you input the number of matches that have been played then you list the results of each match.

Each row in the list has the form of HOME_TEAM_ID | AWAY_TEAM_ID | HOME_TEAM_GOALS | AWAY_TEAM_GOALS

So for example if the user entered (the first line is the number of matches):

```
2
0 1 5 0 
2 3 0 5
```

My program will then output a row containing: team id, win ratio, win ratio on home games, average point difference in won games ( -1 in case of no home games.) The largest (in terms of point difference) win in a single game and then the ID of that opponent.

```
0 1.000 1.000 5.000 
1 0.000 -1 -1 
2 0.000 0.000 -1 
3 1.000 -1 5.000
```

I've completed most of my program but I'm having difficulty implementing one last part. I want to find out the the largest (in terms of goal difference) win in a single game for each team and then the ID of the opponent which they had their largest win in terms of goal difference. (If there aren't any wins then it should simply output -1.)

My first thought was to just loop through the array, setting a variable to the largest win. For each element, check if its point difference is higher than the variable. If it is, replace the variable with the current element's difference.

However I'm getting a compiler error.

```
1079.c: In function 'main':
1079.c:153:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   maximum = resultTable[0];
           ^
1079.c:157:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     if (resultTable[n] > maximum)
                        ^
1079.c:159:17: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
        maximum  = resultTable[n];
```

Any help about how to find the largest average point difference, over multiple games, against one particular opponent, would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//My local variables
int n;
int i;
int input = 0;
int TEAM_ID = 0, NUM_OF_GAMES = 1, WINS = 3, HOME_GAMES = 2, HOME_WINS = 4, HOME_WIN_RATIO = 6, WIN_RATIO = 5, GD = 7;
int homeTeamID, awayTeamID, homeGoals, awayGoals;

static const int NUM_COLUMNS = 10;
static const int NUM_TEAMS = 30;
double resultTable[30][10];
int BEST_WIN_DIFF = 8, BEST_WIN_OPPONENT = 9;



void takeInput();
void sortData();
void printer();
//This method takes the input from the user for homeTeamID, awayTeamID,homeGoals and awayGoals
void takeInput()
{
    scanf("%d", &input);
    for (n = 0; n < input; n++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &homeTeamID, &awayTeamID, &homeGoals, &awayGoals);
        //calls the sortData function
        sortData();
    }
}
//The table fnction which uses the resultTable variable to put the infomation in a table



void sortData()
{

    int goalDiff = homeGoals - awayGoals;


    //This will increment the home games,home game counter and the away game
    resultTable[homeTeamID][NUM_OF_GAMES]++;
    resultTable[homeTeamID][HOME_GAMES]++;
    resultTable[awayTeamID][NUM_OF_GAMES]++;
    //If the awaygoals is larger than the homegoals then it will set the winner in the results table
    if (homeGoals < awayGoals) {
        resultTable[awayTeamID][WINS]++; //increment away wins
    }
    //If the homegoals is larger than the awaygoals then it will set the winner in the results table
    else if (homeGoals > awayGoals) {
        resultTable[homeTeamID][WINS]++;
        resultTable[homeTeamID][HOME_WINS]++; //increment home wins
    }
    //The goal difference for home and away
    resultTable[homeTeamID][GD] = resultTable[homeTeamID][GD] + (homeGoals - awayGoals);
    resultTable[awayTeamID][GD] = resultTable[awayTeamID][GD] + (awayGoals - homeGoals);



      if (goalDiff > resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF]) {
        resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = goalDiff;
        resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT] = awayTeamID;
    }
    if (-goalDiff > resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF]) {
        resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = -goalDiff;
        resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT] = homeTeamID;
    }
}





//Calculates the win ratio
void winRatio()
{
    for (n = 0; n < 30; n++) {

        //This if determines the home win ratio
        if (resultTable[n][HOME_GAMES] > 0) {

            resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO] = resultTable[n][HOME_WINS]
                / resultTable[n][HOME_GAMES];
        }
        if (resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES] > 0) {

            resultTable[n][GD] = resultTable[n][GD] / resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES];
        }

        //This if determines the win ratio
        if (resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES] > 0) {

            resultTable[n][WIN_RATIO] = resultTable[n][WINS]
                / resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES];
        }
    }
}






//This method prints out the results
void printer()
{
    for (n = 0; n < NUM_TEAMS; n++) {
        if (resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES] != 0) {
            if (resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO] == -1) {
                printf("%d %.3f %.0f %.3f %.0f %.0f\n", n,
                    resultTable[n][WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][GD],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT]);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d %.3f %.3f %.3f %.0f %.0f\n", n,
                    resultTable[n][WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][GD],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT]);
            }    
        }
    }
}
//My main function which will be used to call everyother function
int main(void)
{
     for (n = 0; n < NUM_TEAMS; n++) {
        for (i = 1; i < NUM_COLUMNS; i++) {
            resultTable[n][i] = 0;
        }

        resultTable[n][TEAM_ID] = n;
        resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO] = -1;
        resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = -HUGE_VAL;

    }


  int maximum, location = 1;



  for (n = 0; n < 30; n++)


    scanf("%d", &resultTable[n]);

  maximum = resultTable[0];

  for (n = 0; n < 30; n++)
  {
    if (resultTable[n] > maximum)
    {
       maximum  = resultTable[n];
       location = n+1;
    }
  }

  printf("Maximum element is present at location %d and it's value is %d.\n", location, maximum);
  return 0;



    takeInput();
    winRatio();
    printer();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Making people count the number of lines is not good; computers are better at counting.  You should simply read data lines (with 4 numbers per line) until you reach EOF.  For some reason, systems are frequently specified so that there is a count before the data, but it really is very seldom necessary.  (When it is 'necessary', it is typically because there are N records of one type followed by M records of another type.  That too can be handled differently, with a marker to separate the two sets, for example.)

Comment: (As an aside) If you find yourself using `array[SOME_CONSTANT]` a lot, you have probably chosen a wrong representation for your data. You may want to use a `struct` instead.

Comment: I've realized now that I'm only temporarily storing the data into the array, is there a simple way I can change my code to store the data in the array and use it to compare and find the largest win in a single game?

Comment: Don't use global variables, don't use functions that return void and take no parameters.

Comment: It's always quicker to write code properly, as you are now finding out.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a 2-d array, you should use an array of structs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the information you want (the largest etcetera) from the data you enter into the array because you throw away information you need later to calculate this.

You need to store the input data unchanged into the array, then you can calculate anything from it you want.

In particular, with

```
    //The goal difference for home and away
    resultTable[homeTeamID][GD] = resultTable[homeTeamID][GD] + (homeGoals - awayGoals);
    resultTable[awayTeamID][GD] = resultTable[awayTeamID][GD] + (awayGoals - homeGoals);
```

you remember the difference, but that is not enough to calculate the largest win in a single game for each team. Instead, store both `homeGoals` and `awayGoals`and then later calculate the information you want.

Comment: So would I have to rewrite my entire program to make sure that the input data is stored unchanged in the array or is their a simply fix I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Include `math.h` for `HUGE_VAL`.

```
#include <math.h>
```

Add two extra columns.

```
static const int NUM_COLUMNS = 10;
static const int NUM_TEAMS = 30;
double resultTable[NUM_TEAMS][NUM_COLUMNS];
int BEST_WIN_DIFF = 8, BEST_WIN_OPPONENT = 9;
```

Add them to the `table` function.

```
void table()
{
    int i;
    for (n = 0; n < NUM_TEAMS; n++) {
        for (i = 1; i < NUM_COLUMNS; i++) {
            resultTable[n][i] = 0;
        }

        resultTable[n][TEAM_ID] = n;
        resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO] = -1;
        resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = -HUGE_VAL;
    }
}
```

Add the new code to the end of `sortData`.

```
void sortData()
{
    ...

    int goalDiff = homeGoals - awayGoals;

    if (goalDiff > resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF]) {
        resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = goalDiff;
        resultTable[homeTeamID][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT] = awayTeamID;
    }
    if (-goalDiff > resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF]) {
        resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_DIFF] = -goalDiff;
        resultTable[awayTeamID][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT] = homeTeamID;
    }
}
```

and finally update `printer` to include the extra columns.

```
void printer()
{
    for (n = 0; n < NUM_TEAMS; n++) {
        if (resultTable[n][NUM_OF_GAMES] != 0) {
            if (resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO] == -1) {
                printf("%d %.3f %.0f %.3f %.0f %.0f\n", n,
                    resultTable[n][WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][GD],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT]);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d %.3f %.3f %.3f %.0f %.0f\n", n,
                    resultTable[n][WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][HOME_WIN_RATIO],
                    resultTable[n][GD],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_DIFF],
                    resultTable[n][BEST_WIN_OPPONENT]);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

double resultTable[30][10];

`resultTable[x]` is a pointer to `double [10]`

`resultTable[x]` is a pointer of `double *`

`resultTable[x][y]` is `double`

That is the reason you get the warning

You have more problems in your code

you scanf integers, but pass pointer to double etc etc.

Comment: So should I declare `double resultTable[30][10];` as `double * resultTable[30][10];`

Comment: I do not understand what you want to archive.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm trying to find the largest average point difference so I assumed I should find the largest value in the array first?

Comment: You need to write the function which searches for it. But it was not your question. You asked why warnings.